# sudo upgrade evdi.ko.zst freeze at install

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, display, dkms

I did run `sudo apt update`, and afterwards `sudo apt upgrade`.
Normally, this is all fine but it got stuck for ages. I cancelled the process.

I tried to do it again but the terminal tells me to run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

So I run this but it got stuck again at:

```
Setting up evdi (1.14.2-69) ...
Removing old evdi/1.14.2 module.
Module evdi-1.14.2 for kernel 6.5.0-17-generic (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

evdi.ko.zst:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
depmod...
Deleting module evdi-1.14.2 completely from the DKMS tree.
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.2/source -> /usr/src/evdi-1.14.2

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j12 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-17-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.5.0-17-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.2/build/evdi.ko
Cleaning build area...

evdi.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/
depmod...
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: same issue, any idea?

Comment: same issue here too